# Apache Flink's ingestion time, which wall lock?

Tags: apache-flink, windowing

I wonder which wall clock is used in the case of **ingestion time** configuration in Apache Flink.

[Here](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html), we read that ingestion time "*assigns wall clock timestamps to records as soon as they arrive in the system (at the source)*".

If the source is *non* parallel I suppose that the timestamps associated to incoming tuples are totally ordered, but what if I use a *parallel* source function?
Could it be that the parallel source runs on 2 different machines, thus making it possible to use *2 different wall clocks* for timestamps?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wall clock time of the respective machine is used as the timestamp. Consequently, you might get multiple different timestamps if the clocks of the machines are not properly synced.

#### Update

This also holds true for multiple sources if they are executed on different machines. Each source will use the clock of the machine on which it is running to assign the timestamps.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
So, it is up to me to keep synch.
Plus, the same could happen not only on parallel source, but on 2 different sources, am I right? If so, could you add this fact to your answer?

Comment: Yes you're right. If the operators of the different sources run on different machines, then they will use the clocks of the machine on which they run.